# getAnnotations on Scala class fields

Tags: java, scala, reflection

I'm trying to use a Java library (JOhm) with Scala and noticed it fails when the lib tries to read the annotations on the fields of my Scala classes with something like `field.isAnnotationPresent(Id.class)`.

The annotations are defined in Java with:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Id {

}
```

So they should be available on runtime. However, if I try:

```
scala> import redis.clients.johm._
import redis.clients.johm._

scala> class myClass(@Id var id: java.lang.Long)
defined class myClass

scala> new myClass(id = null)
res0: myClass = myClass@5157cfbc

scala> res0.getClass.getDeclaredFields
res1: Array[java.lang.reflect.Field] = Array(private java.lang.Long myClass.id)

scala> res0.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map(_.getAnnotations)
res2: Array[Array[java.lang.annotation.Annotation]] = Array(Array())
```

Then I manage to get the fields (thanks to StackOverflow users…) but I still cannot access the annotations. What did I do wrong?

Comment: There are meta annotation to tell Scala where to put the annotation exactly: http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to 'soc' for [reference provided](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package), there is a definitive answer: "By default, annotations on (val-, var- or plain) constructor parameters end up on the parameter...".

The annotation in question is defined for FIELD elements with run-time retention, while it's being applied to a scala constructor argument (PARAMETER).

I had the same situation recently trying to use a JAXB FIELD level @XmlElement annotation on a scala constructor "var" parameter - didn't work for me either.

I solved my JAXB issue by defining a distinct field in the class, and initializing it from the constructor's parameter list (eliminating the 'val/var' keyword).  In your case that might look like:

```
class myClass(_id: java.lang.Long) {
    @Id var id = _id
}
```

The reference suggests two other alternatives:

1. Changing(adding) element type of the annotation to (include) PARAMETER; this is only viable if the source is available.
2. Use the [target package in 2.9.2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.target.package), which has been renamed to [meta package for 2.10](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.annotation.meta.package), to re-classify (re-target) the annotation to an underlying field (or other option).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually reproduced in the REPL the exact problem I had in my code (I've tried to log annotations directly from my Scala program, and couldn't). So the example I posted here may not work because it is in the REPL, but then my code fails for another reason.

Comment: You are completely right. Defining fields distinctly solves the problem. Saved my night, thanks!